# Trying to make an ammeter to measure 5mA of current and having some difficulties and confusions

Tags: circuit-analysis, meter

I am a beginner in electronics.
I have a meter which is (0.13V)(130ohms)(1mA) rated. I am not inserting the meter for now(don't want to destroy it) instead, I am trying to use a dummy loader.

Here is the circuit drawing that I made for the whole process and I have some question which I will include in the photo.

But the main question is, is it right that I am giving 0.13V from the power supply???

[image: Drawing]

**- Questions**

1. To determine the shunt resistance, am I supposed to calculate with 5ma or 4ma? I did with 4mA and got 32.5ohms. R= (0.13/0.004)ohms.
2. How to measure the current from the dummy loader. I have drawn a setup process to do it. Is it correct? Is the breaking of the circuit correct? I will use a breadboard(which is making harder for me) [shown in the picture]
   [image: Setup]
3. How to make it work?

**Here is what I tried and come up with many confusions.**

[image: this is what I tried]

I just want to know what does it mean by 1.36mA? is it current drop or something?

I hope someone will assist me with this. I am sorry for inserting a lot of pictures, I just wanted myself clear and the reader to be clear what I am talking about. Its 4AM(working on it) I will reply in the morning. Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

Can your power supply deliver 0.13 V accurately?

As you are developing a current meter, it would be better to supply it with a current. Perhaps set the power supply to 5 V, and use a resistor in series, 1 kΩ for 5 mA, 5 kΩ for 1 mA (that's approximate, set the PSU to 5.13 V to account for the voltage drop you expect on your meter).

At its design voltage of 130 mV, the meter will pass 1 mA. If you want a total 5 mA to read full scale, then you need to shunt 4 mA past the meter. To do this at 130 mV, you need a shunt resistor of 130m / 4m = 32.5 Ω, which you have calculated correctly.

It's not clear where you get your figure of 1.36 mA from. If your power supply is delivering 130 mV, and your DMM is reading 130 mV across the shunt resistor as you've shown, then you would calculate the current through the shunt resistor  as 130m / 32.5 = 4 mA.

Perhaps your power supply has an output current meter and is reading 1.36 mA? If it's a power supply capable of delivering 1 A or more, then what you're seeing is the power supply's zero-error on its output meter. The data sheet for the PSU will/should tell you how accurate the meter is, +/- 10 mA would be not uncommon for a meter on a 1 A power supply.

Perhaps you have inserted a current reading meter in series with your power supply, and that reads 1.36 mA? Have you allowed for the voltage drop across this meter, it will reduce the 130 mV from the PSU to the resistor under test, and so reduce the current flowing through it. That's partly why we tend to test current meters with current sources rather than voltage sources, the error due to a series meter would be far less if you used 5 V and a 1k resistor to supply a known current. You wouldn't need a current meter in series anyway, because you could calculate it from voltage drop across the 1k resistor. Use your DMM to check voltage drops across all the components in your setup.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvRSQd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Question : if I form the circuit in breadboard, how can I be sure using DMM that the meter will work and won’t  burn out. And thank you so much. Also do we care about electron flow or current(+ to -)

Comment: There are always problems with breadboard contacts, avoid if you can, especially for small things like this, especially if you have measurements that don't make sense. Electrons add nothing to the model, not at this level. A complication with no benefit. In my 40 years in the engineering business, I have never worried about what electrons are doing. At school, we did a Hall voltage experiment, and a CRT experiment, both of which involved electrons. But as a working engineer, never, and I've done RF, precision analog, FPGA, power supply, low noise synthesis, never needed them!

Comment: I send 0.13V through the power supply. I thought if i test the current across the shunt(which is in series way) i will get 4mA. But instead i got 1.36mA

Comment: Thank you so much again. This current and electron always confusing

Comment: yo don't send 130 mV THROUGH the power supply, you measure 130 mV ACROSS the power supply. How do you test the current THROUGH the shunt (not ACROSS it)? Draw a schematic of the meter connection, or comment on my suggested circuit for whether it's right or wrong.

Comment: I am supposed to use breadboard only. Thats the problem

Comment: Breadboard just means more things to go wrong. If you've got to use it, then you've got to use it, but you've got to be extra imaginative about where bad connections could cause confusing results. Basically every connection with breadboard may be open, or high resistance, suspect everything. It could be dirt on the breadboard contacts or device leads, or the previous user has forced a too big lead into the hole, and strained the breadboard contacts.

Comment: Based on your connection. Before placing the actual meter, i have to check the voltage drop across the shunt (with the dummy loader in paralell 130ohms or without it?). If I get 130mV then I will be sure that it is working. Am I correct?

Comment: if the supply is delivering 5 mA, then to get 130 mV across your 'meter emulator', you would need both the 32.5 ohm shunt and the 130 ohm dummy meter load in parallel, as you have 4 mA through the first, and 1 mA through the second, with that voltage across them.

Comment: Thank you so so so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is correct, to measure 5 mA full scale on a 1 mA 130\$\Omega\$ meter you would need 4 mA to go through the shunt, that's  $$\frac{1mA\cdot130\Omega}{4mA} = 32.5\Omega$$.

In your test setup you have a power supply set to 0.13 V across the shunt and are then measuring the voltage across it. With that setup you're just measuring the supply voltage. You would need to use a current supply outputting 4 mA through the shunt, then you can read the voltage across it and it should be 0.13 V.

Comment: So i hafta send current through the power supply?  I thought power supply only send voltage